# Best way to change disks with Intel Rapid Storage Technology 10.8.0.1068; only one disk in current array

Tags: windows-server-2003, raid, software-raid

I have a raid 1 array which is currently missing one disk. I want to change the system over to two completely new disks. I currently have Intel Rapid Storage Technology 10.8.0.1068 installed. What is the simplest way to move the system over to the two new disks? The OS is Windows 2003, disks are sata.

Intel provides guidance for migrating a normal, fully functional raid 1 array to new disks in http://www.intel.com/support/chipsets/imsm/sb/CS-030751.htm. But I only have one disk in place right now and thus a degraded array.

I think I can go with what Intel suggests in that document. I don't have to pull an existing disk; it's already out. But otherwise, does anyone see an issue with my situation and just adapting the intel recommended process?

Comment: Are the two new disks the same size as the old one? I'm wondering if you could put one of the new disks in, let the array rebuild, take the old disk out and replace it with the second new disk.  EDIT: Should have read your link first, I guess the new disks are larger.

Comment: Thanks Chris, yes they are larger disks. One thing that strikes me, not as a problem but as a point of interest, is that we're normally told to use identical hdd with raid. Here, in the up-sizing instructions from Intel, it's clearly ok to use dissimilar disks. I wonder why this is so?

Comment: Performance is optimal with two identical drives because of similar disk behavior, but it can still work otherwise.